# Windows Chrome not loading all woff or otf font files

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I have two different font styles, Light and Regular that render correctly on Mac OS X Chrome 35 and Android chrome, but does not render correctly on Windows 7 Chrome 35.

Here is a sample of how the font rendering looks:

[image: Windows VS Mac OS X]

The issue is that only one of my font files are being loaded. `mp-light.woff` should also be loaded in the below image.

[image: Font files on Windows Chrome]

Here is what my SASS code looks like.

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Light'
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: normal
  src: local("Myriad Pro Light"), url('mp-light.woff') format("woff"), url('mp-light.otf') format('opentype')


@font-face
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular'
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: normal
  src: local("Myriad Pro Regular"), url('mp-regular.woff') format("woff")
```

I have also tried using an `otf` font which also does not load.

Comment: My guess is that Chrome detects that Myriad Pro is being used illegally (without copyright holder’s permission) and therefore refuses to use it. Check the console log for error messages.

Comment: No errors in the console :(

Answer (score 0):

I was updating my font server and for that I was going through number of articles available online, when I [found that the Google Fonts API serves a different WOFF file to Chrome/Windows than it does to Chrome/OSX](http://michaelboeke.com/blog/2013/09/10/Self-hosting-Google-web-fonts/). Windows and OSX use different type rendering engines. I assume Google Fonts serves different font files to compensate for the differences.